# Android can not access web content even the login is successful

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, android-intent, authentication

I have a problem loging in to our company webpage using my app that I coded. When I use the toast message it can tell if the login is successful or not. But when I insert the INTENT and moving to the next activity which will view the content of the webpage (after the successful login) I can only view the "LOGIN WEBPAGE" of the company, not the content. Correct code or addition to my code is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Below are my codes:

This is our company's webpage:  http://www.allianceinmotion.com/members.asp

LOGIN ACTIVITY:

```
package com.example.packagename;

imports ..... ;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private ProgressDialog pDialog; 
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://vo.aimglobalinc.com/control/con_login.asp";
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser(); 
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

private EditText user, pass;
private Button mSubmit, mRegister;
ConnectionDetector cd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    Intent i1 = getIntent();
    i1.getExtras().getInt("login");
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i1);

    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
    pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_password);

    mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_register);

    mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
    mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

}

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet(); 
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_login:
                if (isInternetPresent) {
                    new AttemptLogin().execute();

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "This requires an internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;

            case R.id.btn_register:
                //Intent i = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
                //startActivity(i);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }


        class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            boolean failure = false;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Attempting to login...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();

            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                String username = user.getText().toString();
                String password = pass.getText().toString();

                try {

                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", username));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pword", password));

                    Log.d("request!", "starting");

                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                    Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                    return json.getString("success");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                return null;

            }
            /**
            * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
            * **/

            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                pDialog.dismiss();

                if (result.equals("true")) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MyAccounts.class); 
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please enter the correct username and password.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }

        }

}
```

MYACCOUNTS ACTIVITY (where I suppose to access the content of the page after succeessful login)

```
package com.example.packagename;

imports ..... ;


public class MyAccounts extends Activity {

private WebView mWebView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mWebView = new WebView(this);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.allianceinmotion.com/members.asp");
    //mWebView.loadUrl("http://vo.aimglobalinc.com/r2bs.asp");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    this.setContentView(mWebView);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
}
```

Using jsonlint.org, when i validate the URL from my LOGIN activity, here is the output:

```
{
"success": "failed",
"message": "Invalid username or password"
 }
```

Comment: can you show us the JSON output

Comment: Your 2nd activity needs to pass the cookies returned by the successful login from the first activity.  Those cookies will identify your Android client as the same client that just logged in.

Comment: @EJK, how to code it in my activities?

Comment: There are a variety of things wrong with your approach, and it's not quite clear what you're having difficulties with. Firstly, your login request is clearly failing with invalid credentials. Secondly, you're not passing any credentials from one activity to another. Finally, you're not using those credentials when loading URLs in your WebView.

Comment: @PaulLammertsma, appreciate your comment.. yes, I am still new in programming and just puzzling out every codes that I encounter in the blogs and tutorials. 

My code above is responding right using message toast,(if my login / password are correct or wrong). My problem here right now is how to insert the "android code for cookies" to use it on the web sessions.